# OpenAI API error: "Unrecognized request argument supplied"

Tags: openai-api, fine-tuning

I'm receiving an error when calling the OpenAI API. It's not recognizing `file` argument, which I submitted to the API.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php

// Define your OpenAI API key and the endpoint
$apiKey = 'sk-TOh**********************************';
$endpoint = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/davinci/completions';

// File ID of the uploaded data
$fileId = 'file-FlW6jPfNuuq1lTak91AjMj2j';

// Product name
$productName = '6 pack fresh grannies apples';

// Prompt to use the file ID as a reference
$prompt = "Given the following data from the uploaded file $fileId, categorize the product '$productName':";

// Prepare the cURL request data
$data = [
    'prompt' => $prompt,
    'max_tokens' => 1, // Adjust the token limit as needed
    'file' => $fileId // Reference the file by ID
];

// Prepare the cURL request
$ch = curl_init($endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $apiKey,
    'Content-Type: application/json',
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

// Execute the cURL request
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Check for cURL errors
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'cURL error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    // Parse the API response as JSON
    $responseData = json_decode($response, true);
echo "<pre>",print_r($responseData),"</pre>";
    // Extract and display the category
    $category = $responseData['choices'][0]['text'];
    echo "Product '$productName' belongs to the category: $category";
}

// Close the cURL session
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Here is the data of the file I uploaded:

```
{"prompt": "fruits", "completion": "apples, bananas, oranges, grapes, strawberries"}
{"prompt": "vegetables", "completion": "carrots, broccoli, spinach, lettuce, tomatoes"}
{"prompt": "dairy", "completion": "milk, cheese, yogurt, butter, cream"}
{"prompt": "meat", "completion": "chicken, beef, pork, lamb, turkey"}
{"prompt": "bakery", "completion": "bread, muffins, cookies, cakes, pies"}
```

Here is the error I'm receiving:

```
[error] => Array
(
  [message] => Unrecognized request argument supplied: file
  [type] => invalid_request_error
  [param] => 
  [code] => 
)
```

What am I doing wrong? I've tried searching for the answer and also looking at OpenAI documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

You're trying to pass `file` as a parameter to the [Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/completions-api) endpoint, which is not a valid parameter. You can't pass any parameter you make up to the Completions API endpoint.

#### Solution

See the [complete list](https://beta.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create) of parameters you can pass to the Completions API endpoint:

- `model`
- `prompt`
- `suffix`
- `max_tokens`
- `temperature`
- `top_p`
- `n`
- `stream`
- `logprobs`
- `echo`
- `stop`
- `presence_penalty`
- `frequency_penalty`
- `best_of`
- `logit_bias`
- `user`

---

Also, all [Engines API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/deprecations/2022-06-03-legacy-endpoints) endpoints are deprecated.

[image: Deprecated]

Use the [Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/completions-api) endpoint.

Change the URL from this...

```
https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/davinci/completions
```

...to this.

```
https://api.openai.com/v1/completions
```